# Google play resources where not found

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-play-services

First of all. Please do not lock or report this thread. I've tried all similar stackoverflow questions and none have fixed my problem!

Since I've added the google play services lib to my project (and the external JAR file)
I keep getting the same error over and over again.
[image]

I've downloaded the google play libs with my SDK manager, I've imported the project and then I referred to the play library in my app and added the external JAR file.

Pictures:
[image]

[image]

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong or how I can fix this problem?
I'm just trying to make my app login with Google+ really..

Thank you
~Yenthe

Comment: you should not add it as external jar. you should reference the google play services library in your android projecg

Comment: How would I reference it correctly then?

Comment: Please go through this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: you need the project resources as well as the jar. copy /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib into your project dir (gradle) or workspace (eclipse) and reference as a library project.

Answer (score 1):

```
Since I've added the google play services lib to my project (and the external JAR file) I keep getting the same error over and over again.
```

Its a library project and you to reference the same in your android project.

`I've imported the project and then I referred to the play library in my app and added the external JAR file`.

Remvoe the external jar. Reference the library project as below.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
 If you are using android-studio follow the steps in the above link under the title **Using Android Studio:**

If you are using eclipse as a in IDE.

Copy the google-play services_lib library project to your workspace (folder where your android map project is). The library project can be found under the following path.

```
<android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project .
```

Import the library project to your eclipse

**Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse the     workspace  import the library project**. You can check if it is library project. Right click on the library project. Goto properties. Click Android on the left panel. You will see Is Library checked.

Right click on your android project. Goto properties. Choose Android on the left panel. Click on Add and browse the library project. Select the same. Click ok and apply

[image]

Comment: Well I really have the same.. You can see that here. http://imgur.com/iNaAFmR
If I browse to the folder itself from SDK under the path C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib I cannot add that library though.. I'll send a screen in a second!

Comment: @Yenthe then you said you added the jar to your andorid project

Comment: Yeah I have removed the JAR file and only kept the library. So I've only kept this:  imgur.com/iNaAFmR

Comment: @Yenthe if you have referenced then clean and build your project and remove the jar

Comment: it still gives the same error :/ Are there any other things that I should do that I could have probably missed?

Comment: @Yenthe well i suggest you remove the external jar. Reference the library project again. then clean and build your project and make sure you have updated google play services which is rev 13 i guess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42196/discussion-between-yenthe-and-raghunandan)

Comment: Just a heads up for everybody who reads this, I still have no solution.